QWC2 measurement tool almost doubles it's results
I have set up QWC2 with my project made in QGIS. I have strange behaviour of the measurement tool which shows different results of same measure in QWC2 than in QGIS. I can say that QGIS's results are correct. QWC2 multiplies the same result by around 1.6, which looks like mile->km conversion.
My project uses EPSG:3857 CRS which is set as projection on both sides, in QGIS project and QWC2 configuration. It contains layers EPSG:4326 which are shown correctly on pseudomercator projection.
I have tried many combinations of settings but I am not able to fix this. Any suggestion where to look?
QWC measurement:

QGIS measurement:


Okay, problem is definitely in ellipsoid settings which is ignored by QWC2 settings.

Problem solved, one just need to add this:
"geodesicMeasurements":true,

to config.json.

Unfortunately I cannot offer a solution, just the explanation:
If you switch the QGIS measurement to Cartesian, you see the same value I presume?
Then QWC2 is measuring in the project's units, which for EPSG:3857 are meters that get longer and longer the further away from the equator you are.
You are getting EPSG:3857 meters, not meters measured on the ground or meters measured with geodesic calculations.

Yes, you are right, this is exactly whats going on and it's a bug in QWC2.
